# The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine that prevents it from being opened or locked

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, locked

I have used MS Access DB 2010 as a BackEnd for the application that i built using C#.NET. I don't have any queries saved in the database, Rather the queries are saved within the application code and runs using OleDB, ODBC connection.

When multiple user use the application they are getting "The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'XXXXXX' that prevents it from being opened or locked."

I need to resolve this issue. I am looking for suggestion on how to.

The DB is set up to be in Shared mode with the other options set as shareable. And I am aware that Access Db can handle maximum 255 Concurrent connection.

I have a lot of queries running as part of user triggered actions. All the queries are placed in a Try{} Catch{} block. I have opened and closed the connection right away after a query is performed so that the connection is released.

Now if errors are thrown from one try catch, then it recursively throws other errors from other nested try catch blocks.... is that what is locking the DB?

When multiple users use the application they are getting an error as "The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'XXXXXX' that prevents it from being opened or locked."

Comment: Googling for that error message gives many links. To avoid us giving you suggestions you have already tried, please list the links you have already read and tried to apply.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following links. I have also used the link below to Enable all macro and ActiveX Warnings: 
http://bluescreensolutions.blogspot.com/2012/04/access-2007-database-has-been-placed-in.html
http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/split/index.htm

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-mso_2007/the-database-has-been-placed-in-a-state-by-user/f1a506cc-4389-41eb-9efc-a881a657ffb5?auth=1&page=2

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=202641

http://www.myaccesstips.com/deploy/deploy.html

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=198758

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=295530

https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=271753